# ACF to PDF how to generate a file?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

On my website, you need to print an ACF fields to PDF file. how can this be done?
I created a custom post type and enter this data through custom fields. How to print in PDF these fields

Comment: You'll need a PHP library for this. Try [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Comment: You want to print the entire page? or just the acf field?

Comment: made using DK PDF